# Pyqt5 how to make the dialog to blink in case the user by mistake clicks on the parent window or anywhere else

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

**Pyqt5** how to make the dialog to blink in case the user by mistake clicks on the parent window or anywhere else.

Comment: Make that dialog modal to its parent?

Comment: can you please tell how to do that. I have already tried setting window.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate the desired behavior of modal dialogs just do this:

```
QDialog dialogParent;

QDialog dialogChild(&dialogParent); // Note the parent-child relationship
dialogChild.setModal(true);         // Child is modal to its parent

// Show both dialogs
dialogParent.show();
dialogChild.show();
```